# Issue with conversion from string to double

Tags: double, uipath

I am not able to convert my string to double.I am getting below error

conversion from string to double is not valid

I have tried below approach but all are giving me same error. I am using Assign activity in uipath with intvalue defined as double and row.Item("TaxResult") retrieves the value from excel

- intval = Val(row.Item("Tax Result").ToString.Trim)
- intVal = Double.Parse(row.Item("Tax Result").ToString.Trim , double)
- intVal = cDbl(row.Item("Tax Result").ToString.Trim)

Out of the above three first one is returning to me 0 value while the below two is giving me an error

"conversion from string to double is not valid"

Tax Result column in excel stores the value like (5.2, 19.8, 98.87). I want to sum all these value as part of my requirement

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the `.Item` after row, it should just be `row("Tax Result")`

Ideally you should use a `Double.TryParse()` to try and avoid any exceptions if it cant convert to Double.

This can be achieved using an If Statement as seen below, if the Try Parse is successful the string can be converted using `Double.Parse(row("Tax Result").ToString.Trim)` and on failure I have assigned `intval` to `0` but you could put handling here to handle if it can't convert the number

[image: Screenshot of Sequence]